# Fill irregular x-axis array with zeroes

Tags: numpy, histogram, fill

i have two arrays:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10])
y = np.array([3, 5, 9, 13, 4, 6])
```

I want x to be a continuous sequence from 1-10. Y should be "0" at the new x values that are added.
In other words, i'd like the arrays to be:

```
x_ = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
y_ = np.array([3, 5, 0, 9, 13, 0, 0, 4, 0, 6])
```

How can i do this?
I'm planning to use these arrays for a pyplot.histogram in order to plot the point densities.

Thank you

Comment: x and y don't have same number of elements and y_ has a 10 in the end. Can you please check if your arrays are correct and if yes, explain the desired output.

Comment: Corrected it, is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

My idea:

```
        x_ = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
        y_ = np.zeros_like(x_)
        y_[x] = y
```

Damnit, i thought i solved it but i was wrong. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Looks almost correct to me: `x_ = np.arange(1,11)` `y_ = np.zeros(x_.size,y.dtype)` `y_[x-1] = y`.

Comment: Thank you Paul Panzer! I can accept this answer in 2 days